# How can I search for 'new' items ONLY in Amazon.ca?

Tags: search, amazon

I was trying to find a 'new' laptop in Amazon and failed.

It is showing a **lot** of search results which includes 'old' and 'refurbished' items as well.

I scrolled through 5 or 6 pages, almost all items are 'old' ones.

How can I ask Amazon.ca to show **only new items**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either try to include a year in the search bar or select **Sort by: Newest Arrivals** (or both):

[image: 0]

Comment: I just tried in 'amazon.ca' but the results are weird. Please refer https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=laptop+2019&s=date-desc-rank&qid=1557779052&ref=sr_st_date-desc-rank

Comment: try: https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=laptop+2019&i=electronics&crid=7FEDIRLDG8ND&sprefix=laptop+2019%2Caps%2C240&ref=nb_sb_ss_c_2_11

Comment: I also noticed, when I select any filter criteria from left panel ( ie. RAM size), "Sort By: Newest arrivals" option disappeared :-(

Comment: or: https://www.amazon.com/s?k=laptop+2019&s=date-desc-rank&crid=1NKUHWVQE4YCU&qid=1557779469&sprefix=laptop+2019%2Celectronics%2C316&ref=sr_st_date-desc-rank

Comment: or: https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=laptop&s=date-desc-rank&qid=1557779824&ref=sr_st_date-desc-rank

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to upvote :-(